# removing the last line of a file not working?

Tags: sed, cat, head

I have this TXT file that is created by a bash script and at the end I want to remove the last line of that file that is an empty one.

```
head --lines=-1 r3.txt > r4.txt

sed '$d' r3.txt > r4.txt

cat r3.txt | head -n -1  > r4.txt
```

r4.txt continues to have the last empty line...

I am on a linux CentOS 6.x server.

Does this have anything to do with line endings (unix x windows)?

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure there's an empty line at the end? Note that a correctly formatted Unix text file ends in a linefeed character (because it is a line ending character, not a line separation character, in Unix). What does the end of the output of `xxd r3.txt` look like?

Comment: so, must be this I am seeing. I was thinking that this extra ending character was an empty line. Thanks. Please make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is no empty line at the end.

Unix text files consist of lines, each of which ends in a line feed character (`'\n'`, `^J`, `0x0a`). That is, the linefeed character is not a line separator, but a line ending character. This is especially also true for the last line, and therefore for the file as a whole.

For example, a text file containing

```
abc
def
```

will look like this when looked at with `xxd`:

```
0000000: 6162 630a 6465 660a                      abc.def.
```

You can clearly see the single `0a` at the end. On the other hand, if there's an additional an empty line at the end, you get

```
0000000: 6162 630a 6465 660a 0a                   abc.def..
```

Note that now there are *two* `0a` bytes.

You can also see this with `wc -l` which counts lines. On the first file, it will give `2`, on the second file it will give `3`. Note also that if the final line feed is missing (which means the file is not actually a valid text file, although most tools will be able to treat it anyway), `wc` will only count one line.